# How do you connect things to 1/4" PEX?

Tags: pex, pipe-fitting

I'm currently doing research on an upcoming major re-plumbing project, and have run across a bit of a mystery...

Lowe's sells these riser supply lines ([faucet version](https://www.lowes.com/pd/ReliaBilt-3-8-in-Compression-30-in-Pex-Flexible-Riser-Supply-Line/5013470635), [toilet version](https://www.lowes.com/pd/ReliaBilt-3-8-in-Compression-20-in-Pex-Flexible-Riser-Supply-Line/5013470633)) that are described as being PEX.  I was thinking about using a central PEX manifold with valves, to avoid the need for stop valves at each fixture, so being able to run PEX all the way to the fixtures seems appealing.  But the lines are 3/8" O.D., which is apparently 1/4" nominal size - and Lowe's doesn't carry ANY fittings whatsoever for 1/4" PEX, even though they actually stock 1/4" PEX pipe in addition to these risers.  In fact, I can't find 1/4" PEX fittings ANYWHERE online.  I must be missing something - why would people buy these pipes if they can't connect anything to them?

Comment: Normally the lines from a whole-house manifold are 1/2" (so called) - 5/8" outside diameter, 0.475" inside diameter. Sometimes 3/8". Using 1/4"  for a significant distance would cause a significant pressure drop/flow restriction. Fittings for 1/2" PEX directly to fixtures are commonly available.

Comment: Depending on *your applicable code*, you *may* still need stop valves at the fixtures.

Comment: Stop valves at the fixture are never a bad idea. If there's a problem you don't want to run through the house to turn off the water.